# nltk.grammar.is_terminal('str') always returns true?

Tags: python, list, terminal, grammar, nltk

how do I define the grammar used by `nltk.grammar.is_terminal()` ? No matter what on what object I cast this method, I always get A `true` as a return. But instead I wanna have checked whether a list called `wordlist` contains productions defined in a context-free-grammar safed under `grammar.cfg`.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the code on https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/grammar.py

```
def is_nonterminal(item):
    """
    :return: True if the item is a ``Nonterminal``.
    :rtype: bool
    """
    return isinstance(item, Nonterminal)


def is_terminal(item):
    """
    Return True if the item is a terminal, which currently is
    if it is hashable and not a ``Nonterminal``.
    :rtype: bool
    """
    return hasattr(item, '__hash__') and not isinstance(item, Nonterminal)
```

Although I'm not sure how the functions should be used, the default value for `is_terminal()` for any string input is always `True`.

Because, firstly, all strings contains the `__hash__` attribute, it's a function to hash string, see [https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.**hash**](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__)

```
>>> astring = 'foo bar'
>>> astring.__hash__
<method-wrapper '__hash__' of str object at 0x7f06bb0cbcc0>
>>> astring.__hash__()
8194924035431162904
```

Secondly, all a string is surely not a `Nonterminal` object in `NLTK` because the class `Nonterminal` is:

```
class Nonterminal(object):
    """
    A non-terminal symbol for a context free grammar.  ``Nonterminal``
    is a wrapper class for node values; it is used by ``Production``
    objects to distinguish node values from leaf values.
    The node value that is wrapped by a ``Nonterminal`` is known as its
    "symbol".  Symbols are typically strings representing phrasal
    categories (such as ``"NP"`` or ``"VP"``).  However, more complex
    symbol types are sometimes used (e.g., for lexicalized grammars).
    Since symbols are node values, they must be immutable and
    hashable.  Two ``Nonterminals`` are considered equal if their
    symbols are equal.
    :see: ``CFG``, ``Production``
    :type _symbol: any
    :ivar _symbol: The node value corresponding to this
        ``Nonterminal``.  This value must be immutable and hashable.
    """
```

So a string goes through both criteria of (1) having an `__hash__` attribute and (2) is not a `Nonterminal` object. Thus the `nltk.grammar.is_terminal()` always returns True for all strings.

Then how do I make it return a False, only when you load a grammar and then read a Nonterminal object in the grammar, possibly only when an object is specifically created or casted as a Nonterminal, e.g. http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/parse/pchart.html